# Flutter : TextFormField real device keyboard problem ( Error: Composing region changed by the framework. Restarting the input method )

Tags: flutter, input, keyboard, frameworks, textformfield

I implemented a Form page with getx state management. Everything is fine when I test it on simulator. But When I used real device for test, I faced a problem.
Actually Here is a one page for two type works.

1. For New Users
2. Update User

**For new user**, form textfield `controller` initial value is null. And it's always work fine until use `unChanged` function. By the way, I Don't need `onChanged` when I using `Controller`

**For Update User**, I initialled a value on `Textformfield` `controller` inside build. This `Textformfield` work fine on simulator. But I run it real device, and click on TextFormField, my cursor move to first automatically . And when I unfocused `TextformField` after typing value, my last value is vanished. And it's show me this type error:

```
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(30962): getCursorCapsMode on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(30962): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
I/TextInputPlugin(30962): Composing region changed by the framework. Restarting the input method.
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(30962): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(30962): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(30962): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
```

**> Here is my ControllerPage**

```
class UserFormController extends GetxController {
  RxBool isNewUser = false.obs;

  final GlobalKey<FormState> formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  late TextEditingController nameCtrl, jobCtrl;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    nameCtrl = TextEditingController();
    jobCtrl = TextEditingController();
    super.onInit();
  }

  @override
  void onClose() {
    nameCtrl.dispose();
    jobCtrl.dispose();
    super.onClose();
  }
}
```

**> And here is my view page**

```
class UserFormScreen extends GetView<UserFormController> {
  final bool isNewUser;
  final Data? user;
  const UserFormScreen({Key? key, required this.isNewUser, this.user})
      : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double _width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double _height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    final UserFormController formCtrl = Get.put(UserFormController());
    if (!isNewUser) {
      formCtrl.nameCtrl.text = "${user!.firstName} ${user!.lastName}";
    }
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(isNewUser ? "Create New User" : "Update User"),
      ),
      body: GestureDetector(
        behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
        onTap: () {
          FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
        },
        child: SizedBox(
          height: _height,
          width: _width,
          child: Form(
            key: formCtrl.formKey,
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 40,
                  ),
                  CustomTextField(
                    labelText: "Name",
                    hintText: "ex. Robert",
                    controller: formCtrl.nameCtrl,
                    validator: (value) {
                      return formCtrl.validateName(value!);
                    },
                    onChanged: (val) {
                      formCtrl.nameCtrl.text = val;
                      formCtrl.nameCtrl.selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(
                          TextPosition(offset: formCtrl.nameCtrl.text.length));
                    },
                  ),
                  CustomTextField(
                    labelText: "Job",
                    hintText: "ex. Manager",
                    controller: formCtrl.jobCtrl,
                    validator: (value) {},
                  ),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();

                      if (validateAndSave(formCtrl.formKey)) {
                        if (isNewUser) {
                          //create new

                          formCtrl.createNewUser();
                        } else {
                          //update
                          formCtrl.updateUser(user!.id);
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      isNewUser ? "Create" : "Update",
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this error this way:

1. run `flutter clean`
2. run `flutter pub get`
3. uninstall the app

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. In my situation I wanted from one textField focus to another textfield.

Even though in initialiazed focusNode for each fields, I had this error:  *Composing region changed by the framework. Restarting the input method.*

The mistake I made was that I didn't paste focusNode in my customTextFormField, so that textFormFields were not set by their focuses

If you still have any issues, you can ask me more!

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more? Maybe some code? I'm having the same issue

Comment: https://gist.github.com/behzodfaiziev/cccc7660e22ee8d79c7ffdcd4b548b12

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is:

```
formCtrl.nameCtrl.text = val;
```

No need to set `controller.text` inside `onChanged`